# Warning: the lockfile is being updated to Bundler 2, after which you will be unable to return to Bundler 1

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I put some new gems in my Gemfile and ran `bundle install`.
The installation went successfully, but at the end I got this warning:

> Warning: the lockfile is being updated to Bundler 2, after which you will be unable to return to Bundler 1.

What does this mean - I mean it obviously states that the lockfile is being updated to Bundler2 and I wont be able to return to Bundler 1, and yet, should I be concerned about this? Is there any danger of non-compatibility after this? Why is it updated automatically?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not something to worry about unless you need to use the project with Bundler v1 anywhere. The only non-compatibility will be for developers or environments who can only have Bundler v1 installed.

From [the documentation](https://bundler.io/guides/bundler_2_upgrade.html):

> **What happens if my application needs Bundler 2, but I only have
>   Bundler 1 installed?**
>
> If you try to use Bundler 1 on an application
>   that requires Bundler 2, you’ll see an error message explaining that
>   you need to install Bundler 2. Go ahead and run `gem install bundler`,
>   and then it should work.

This is an irreversible change, so you can’t go backwards.

> **Can I downgrade my application from Bundler 2 to Bundler 1?**
>
> Bundler 2 does not provide a way to downgrade a Gemfile back to Bundler 1.
>   Instead, we recommend checking in your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` before
>   you upgrade your application. That way, if something goes wrong, you
>   can revert to the previous commit and go back to using Bundler 1.

If it updated automatically and you didn’t specify the `--bundle` switch, that might be because one of the gems you updated had a dependency on Bundler itself at a more recent version. Check your `Gemfile.lock` and see if any gems have Bundler as a dependency.