# Why gem is not loaded: require gems gives error no such file

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I installed gem 'ssh-net'. From the console I tried to `require` the gem like this:

```
irb(main):009:0* require 'ssh-net'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ssh-net
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from (irb):9
        from /home/csrhub/git/csrhub-api/bin/console:150:in `<top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.1.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `load'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.1.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:63:in `kernel_load'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.1.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.1.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:476:in `exec'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.1.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.1.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.1.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:399:in `dispatch'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.1.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.1.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:476:in `start'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.1.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.1.1/exe/bundle:46:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.1.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:123:in `with_friendly_errors'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-2.1.1/exe/bundle:34:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Then I tried with a gem that works:

```
irb(main):023:0* require 'memcache'
=> false
```

I printed the gems locations:

```
csrhub@csrhub:~/git/csrhub-api$ bundle info 'net-ssh'
  * net-ssh (5.2.0)
        Summary: Net::SSH: a pure-Ruby implementation of the SSH2 client protocol.
        Homepage: https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh
        Path: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/net-ssh-5.2.0


csrhub@csrhub:~/git/csrhub-api$ bundle info 'memcache'
  * memcache-client (1.8.5)
        Summary: A Ruby library for accessing memcached.
        Homepage: http://github.com/mperham/memcache-client
        Path: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/memcache-client-1.8.5
csrhub@csrhub:~/git/csrhub-api$
```

I see that both gems are placed in the same directory. Why `memcache` is invokable and the `ssh-net` is not? What am I missing?

May be it has something to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59477399/warning-the-lockfile-is-being-updated-to-bundler-2-after-which-you-will-be-una) ?

Answer (score 0):

> I installed gem 'ssh-net'.

No, you didn't. You installed the gem [`net-ssh`](https://rubygems.org/gems/net-ssh/), as you can clearly see in the output of `bundle info` that you posted:

> ```
> csrhub@csrhub:~/git/csrhub-api$ bundle info 'net-ssh'
>  * net-ssh (5.2.0)
>        Summary: Net::SSH: a pure-Ruby implementation of the SSH2 client
> ```

Here you can see that the name of the gem is `net-ssh` and not `ssh-net` and that the name of the primary class is `Net::SSH`.

> From the console I tried to `require` the gem like this:
>
> ```rb
> irb(main):009:0* require 'ssh-net'
> LoadError: cannot load such file -- ssh-net
> ```

The primary class in this gem is called [`Net::SSH`](https://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/). (It integrates in the `Net` namespace of the Ruby standard library, which has libraries like [`Net::FTP`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/), [`Net::HTTP`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/), [`Net::IMAP`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/), [`Net::POP`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/pop/rdoc/), [`Net::SMTP`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/), and [`Net::Telnet`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/).)

According to standard Ruby naming conventions, a class named `Net::SSH` should be located in a file named `lib/ssh.rb`. This is the file you need to `require`.

This is also shown in [the very first line of the very first code sample of the very first page of the documentation](https://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/#label-SYNOPSIS-3A):

```rb
require 'net/ssh'
```

> I see that both gems are placed in the same directory. Why `memcache` is invokable and the `ssh-net` is not? What am I missing?

In 99.9% of all cases where a computer tells you it cannot find something, it is because that thing you told it to find is indeed not there. Computers are very, very good at finding things.

The same thing is the case here: you told Ruby

```rb
require 'ssh-net'
```

which means "go through each directory in the `$LOAD_PATH` and look for a file named `ssh-net.rb`". Such a file simply does not exist, ergo, you get a `LoadError` exception.